# When trying to add a new key, all other keys are deleted

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm having trouble adding new keys to a certain path in my RTDB.

**I'm trying to have it so that every time this script is run, it'll create a new key with an ID that's 1 number higher than the last.**

```
var usersRef = ref.child(`users/` + uid);
usersRef.once("value", function (data) {
    var currentID = data.val().currentID;
    var newID = currentID + 1;
    var usersRef = ref.child(`users/` + uid);
    usersRef.update({
        guilds: {
            [currentID]: guildID
        },
        currentID: newID
    });
});
```

This code works fine the first time (when currentID is set to 0), but whenever I attempt to add more keys to the "guilds" path using this same script (with a different "currentID"), the old entry is overwritten and disappears.

Ideally, I'd like it so that a new key in the "guilds" path is added each time, without deleting previous keys in the "guilds" path that have been written

Comment: did you try to console what guilds saving inside. I think your current id is changed with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's `update` essentially works as a `set` on each top-level key in the objec that you pass it. So in your code, Firebase updates only `guilds` and `currentID` and leaves other properties under `/users/$uid` unmodified, but it completely replaces the existing values at `guilds` and `currentID` with the value you specify in this call.

If you want to perform a more granular update under `guilds`, specify its entire path in the `update` call. So something like this:

```
usersRef.update({
    `guilds/${currentID}`: guildID
    currentID: newID
});
```